# What is the maximum data size that can transfer via GPRS

Tags: mobile-application, gprs

**What is the maximum data size that can transfer via GPRS.**

I want to upload  some images from my device (mobile phones,tablets,ipad,etc) to the web (server)

Im developing a **mobile application in J2ME,ANDROID,etc**.In that application i need to upload some images to the server.

So i need the maximum data size will able to upload

All are welcome to give your suggestions.

Comment: I suspect the upper limit is what the customer is willing to pay for. There is no real _technical_ limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you capable of storing any image in device like J2ME/Android then you can upload that to web.No limit on that is there.But the time it takes may be greater if amount of size is much,better you take call on this on the basis of device capabilities mostly for J2ME low end devices.